# How to grab image from blob:http localhost url using either jquery or angularjs or webgl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I would like to know that how can I grab the image(using either jquery or angularjs or WebGL) from the localhost url that is I can get the url of uploaded image file like: blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/87424398-8ee0-4db1-a653-bc18838d6b24, so I need to display the image from this url on my `<div>` element. For me it is showing the error like on displaying it:

```
Unknown number of bits allocated - using default: 32 bits
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of null
    X.parserDCM.parse @ parserDCM.js:362
    (anonymous function) @ loader.js:295
```

For your reference you can look into at: http://slicedrop.com/ .
Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure these are the droids your looking for, but:

```
var a = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(a);
var img = new Image();
img.src = tmppath ;
img.crossOrigin = '';

// after image loading
img.onload = function (): void { //something }
```